# Alpha mask in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

I've looked everywhere and I can't find an answer that works.

I'm trying to make a hole in a texture, by having `"sheet.png"` be the texture and `"hole.png"` being the alpha mask. It's a white picture with a black circle, which is the location I want sheet to have a hole.

How do I do this? This is what I have so far but all it does is draw the two textures on top of each other

```
md3dDev->SetTexture(0, gTexture);
md3dDev->SetTexture(1, holeTexture);

md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);  

md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);

md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE );
md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE );
md3dDev->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG2, D3DTA_CURRENT );

md3dDev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, true);
md3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND,D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);//alpha
md3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND,D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);//alpha
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule: COLOROP goes with COLORARG, ALPHAOP goes with ALPHAARG, don't mix them.

It's not possible getting colorinformation into the alphachannel in the fixed function pipeline. The nearest approach I can think of is preparing the hole-texture so that the information resides in the alphachannel. Then you can use something like this:

```
  // multiply colorchannel from colortexture with diffuse lighting
  d3dSetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP,   D3DTOP_MODULATE);   
  d3dSetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
  d3dSetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_CURRENT);
  // ignore alpha from colortexture
  d3dSetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP,   D3DTOP_SELECTARG1); 
  d3dSetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);

  // ignoring colorchannel from alphatexture
  d3dSetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP,   D3DTOP_SELECTARG1); 
  d3dSetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);
  // get alpha from alphatexture
  d3dSetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP,   D3DTOP_SELECTARG1); 
  d3dSetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
```

This though is pretty obsolete nowadays. Use shaders! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your own shadders, just multiply the alphas together.

```
Output = tex2d(Texture[0], uv)
Output.A *= tex2d(Texture[1], uv).A
```

if you are using the fixed pipeline / emulation of it, then I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: I'm not using any custom shaders. You think that's what I should do?

Comment: @robev Yes, its the way I would go. They can be a little deep to get into to start with. A good tutorial I found was http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/series3.php, admittedly its not for C++, but its more the shader side of things that it teaches anyways.